# Spring Batch Write Exception records separate file

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have Spring Batch read records form XML file and write in to csv file.I need example for, if suppose exception occurred for reading i need to write those records in separate file.

I need any example for writing Exception records with one file along with processed records in another file.

can anyone help on this????

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [ItemListenerSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ItemListenerSupport.html). You can find some useful examples [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#loggingItemProcessingAndFailures)